# Security group with custom IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

While learning AWS, I have come across something weird. Not sure if i am doing something wrong here.

I have a security group inbound rule to allow HTTP traffic from My IP only (just one rule). Now this security group is attached to my EC2 instance. Now when I connect to my EC2 instance using public IP, it connects perfectly and displays the user data that I have given in EC2 instance.

Out of curiosity, I tried to open the EC2 instance with the public IP address from my iPhone, but surprisingly I was able to see the same user data. I am not sure why the IP address rule in the security group didn't work.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're phone is connected to your wifi network?

Comment: You should deactivate wifi on your phone to force it to go via a different network. All devices connected to your wifi will "appear" to be coming from the same public IP address because the router performs NAT.